# Cannot import a Julia package's dependency

Tags: julia

I have a julia package, say 'Foo.jl' that I installed from git. The package is not registered with Pkg registry yet and it has a dependecy, say 'X.jl'. When I run `using X`, julia raises an error saying 'X' is not installed. but running Foo's functions i don't see such error.

Is there a way to fix this? How to make installing `Foo` let me use its dependencies without installing them separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to use packages in Julia you need to add them. For example, if you added the package Plots, then this will add also several other packages that are in the dependencies of Plots. However, you will not be able to use them until you add them explicitly to your environment.

For instance, if you add `Plots.jl`, this will add many dependencies, e.g. the `Tables` package, however you will not be able to do `using Tables` except if you add it to your environment. However, Plots will still make use of the package Tables.

Said that, there are several ways how to add packages in Julia (for a full information see the [Documentation of Pkg.jl](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/stable/managing-packages/#Adding-packages-1)). I will divide them in registered packages, unregistered packages and unregistered packages not on github.

To use Pkg you first have to import it via:

```
using Pkg
```

otherwise you can also use its functionalities in the REPL with the right square bracket `]` and then the command (e.g. `]add Example`)

**Registered Packages:**

```
Pkg.add("Example")
```

**Unregistered Packages on github:**

```
Pkg.add(url="https://github.com/fredrikekre/ImportMacros.jl")
```

**Unregistered local Packages:**

```
Pkg.add(path="path/to/package")
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. So there is no way for one to use the dependency without explicitly `add`ing it using Pkg?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. But why do you not want to add it?

Comment: I don't have anything against adding it :) it's just a force of habit from python where dependencies can also be imported.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `using Foo.X`.

Example: [OhMyREPL.jl](https://github.com/KristofferC/OhMyREPL.jl) depends on [Crayons.jl](https://github.com/KristofferC/Crayons.jl).

```
julia> using OhMyREPL

julia> using OhMyREPL.Crayons

julia> crayon"0000ff" # @crayon_str is exported by Crayons.jl
\e[38;2;0;0;255m
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid needing to register the package is by just using `include` and then include the `.jl` files that you need. If the package is already written like a standard Julia module, you'd probably only need to include the main file.

In this case it would probably be:

```
include("/path/to/Foo.jl")
```

and then you can access the module's functions and objects as

```
Foo.function()
```